# How do I check if an application is running in the GUI?

Tags: bash

I am using a back script to run another bash script if a certain program is not open. I had a look at `lsof` however that also returns a True even if the application is running in the background. I want to detect if it is open in the gui not as a background process. cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ps` to find out whether the process is running in the foreground or in the background.

To quickly test, open a bash shell, lets assume its PID is `13623`

Now start the firefox in the background by `firefox &`
and run `man ps` which will run in the foreground.

from other bash shell if you run :

```
$ ps -O stat --ppid 13623
PID STAT S TTY          TIME COMMAND
13897 Sl   S pts/4    00:00:02 /usr/lib/firefox/firefox
14079 S+   S pts/4    00:00:00 man ps
```

`--ppid 13623` - gives us the processes running on bash shell with PID 13623

`-O stat` - provides the STAT field details

`+` in `STAT` indicates that the process is in the foreground.

`man` is in the foreground and thus the STAT is `S+`

Search for `PROCESS STATE CODES` in `man ps` for more details!

Comment: @a45628 is this the type of background what you were interested in?  Is it relevant for GUI?